# How to properly send documents for signing using docusign API in php

Tags: docusignapi

Am trying to send Documents for signing to a recipient using Docusign. The application was able to print **account id** and **baseurl** in **step 1**

**My Issue** is that in step 2, it throws error

**error calling webservice, status is:401 error text is --> { "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED", "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid." }**

Here is the code

```
<?php

// Input your info here:
$integratorKey = 'Integrator key goes here';
$email = 'login email goes here';
$password = 'password goes here';

$recipient_email = 'recipient@gmail.com';
$name = 'Recipient Name';
$document_name = 'World_Wide_Corp_lorem.pdf';

// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
  
        
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results
echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 2 - Create an envelope with one recipient, one tab, one document and send!
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = "{
  \"emailBlurb\":\"This comes from PHP\",
  \"emailSubject\":\"DocuSign API - Please Sign This Document...\",
  \"documents\":[
    {
      \"documentId\":\"1\",
      \"name\":\"".$document_name."\"
    }
  ],
  \"recipients\":{
    \"signers\":[
      {
        \"email\":\"$recipient_email\",
        \"name\":\"$name\",
        \"recipientId\":\"10\",
        \"tabs\":{
          \"signHereTabs\":[
            {
              \"anchorString\":\"Signature:\",
              \"anchorXOffset\":\"0\",
              \"anchorYOffset\":\"0\",
              \"documentId\":\"1\",
              \"pageNumber\":\"1\"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  \"status\":\"sent\"
}";  

$file_contents = file_get_contents($document_name);

$requestBody = "\r\n"
."\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
."\r\n"
."$data\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"World_Wide_Corp_lorem.pdf\"; documentid=1 \r\n"
."\r\n"
."$file_contents\r\n"
."--myboundary--\r\n"
."\r\n";

// *** append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and as signature request endpoint

$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )
);




$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

//--- display results
echo "Document is sent! Envelope ID = " . $envelopeId . "\n\n";
```

Comment: hi, where is the oauth token that needs to be retrieved first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old Legacy Auth is no longer supported. Not sure where you found this code or any documentation showing this old way of making API calls.

You must use OAuth. You have to get an oauth token by using either [Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/) or [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) and then put it in the header of your call using a "Bearer"

See code:

```
# You will need to obtain an access token using your chosen authentication flow 
$api_client = new \DocuSign\eSign\client\ApiClient($base_path);
$config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Configuration($api_client);
$config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + $access_token);
$users_api = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\UsersApi($api_client);
```